# Add incremental number in duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have SSIS package, which retrieves all records including duplicates. My question is how to add an incremental value for the duplicate records (only the ID and PropertyID).

Eg

Records from a Merge Join

```
ID   Name   PropertyID  Value
1    A      1           123
1    A      1           223
2    B      2           334
3    C      1           22
3    C      1           45
```

Now I need to append an incremental value at the end of the each record as

```
ID   Name   PropertyID  Value  RID
1    A      1           123    1
1    A      1           223    2
2    B      2           334    1
3    C      1           22     1
3    C      1           45     2
```

Since ID 1 & 3 are returned twice, the first record has RID as 1 and the second record as 2.

ID and PropertyID need to be considered to generate the Repeating ID i.e RID.

How can I do it in SSIS or using SQL command?

Update #1:

[image]

Please correct me if I'm wrong, since the data is not stored in any table yet, I'm unable to use the select query using rownumber(). Any way I can do it from the Merge Join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job for you: https://paultebraak.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/rank-partitioning-in-etl-using-ssis/

You will need to write a custom script, something like this:

```
public
class
ScriptMain : UserComponent

{
 string _sub_category = “”;
int _row_rank = 1;

public  override  void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
if (Row.subcategory != _sub_category)
{
_row_rank = 1;
Row.rowrank = _row_rank;

_sub_category = Row.subcategory;
}
else
{
   _row_rank++;
   Row.rowrank = _row_rank;

}

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Deepak, this is what i needed.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT ID, 
       Name, 
       PropertyID, 
       Value, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, PropertyID ORDER BY Value) As RID
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Thanks @zohar for the response, Please see my updated question, I'm not storing the data in any table yet. That mean, i cannot use this query right.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with SSIS, but you wrote in your question "How can I do it in SSIS or using SQL command.". I've shown the relevant SQL command. If that doesn't help, I guess you will have to wait for someone with more SSIS experience than me to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Zohar, Its a start, i'll check how to use this query in the SSIS. Thanks a lot.